# I want to add a class on body when the banner is not shown

Tags: javascript

```js
function bannerCheck() {
  var banner = document.querySelector('.banner-section');
  if (!banner.length) {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('no-banner')
  }
}

bannerCheck();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="banner-section">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, harum?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I write this js but it's not working properly. with this js, it only adds a no-banner class in the body but my requirement is if the banner-section class does not contain any content then a class is added to the body tag

Answer (score 0):

When you are Checking `if (!banner.length)` this will return true, because `document.querySelector('.banner-section')` method returns a single element (not an array), so it does not have a length property.

To check if the `.banner-section` element has any content, you can check if its innerHTML property is an empty string or not.

```
function bannerCheck() {
  var banner = document.querySelector('.banner-section');
  if (!banner.innerHTML.trim()) {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('no-banner');
  }
}

bannerCheck();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the banner has children or not, so instead of checking **banner.length** you need to check **banner.children.length**

```js
function bannerCheck() {
  var banner = document.querySelector('.banner-section');
  if (!banner.children.length) {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('no-banner')
  }
}

bannerCheck();
```

```html
<div class="banner-section">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, harum?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```